# Gearman:PHP session variables & priorities

Tags: php, gearman

I have only just discovered Gearman and it seems pretty much perfect for the job I have in mind - essentially I need to construct, package and return a large PDF document when the user requests it.  I want to

- Hive off this job to a separate process so the user can keep doing other stuff.
- Be able to prioritize document deliver to users who pay.
- Potentially, run the doc generator on a different server.

However, being a Gearman newbie, this poses several questions

- Would the PDF generator script (PHP) have access to the user's session variables?
- From what I have seen in the PHP docs Gearman only allows three priority levels: Low (addTaskLow), Normal (addTask) and High (addTaskHigh).  Is this correct?
- In what way do the addTask?Background versions differ? Would it be right to assume that the priority hierarchy is addTaskHigh,addTask,addTaskLow,addTaskHighBG,addTaskBG & addTaskLowBG?
- Finally, if I do end up running the doc generator on a separate machine would I then loose access to the user's PHP session variables (assuming it is possible in the first place)

I'd much appreciate any help and tips with this.

Comment: Would the PDF generator script (PHP) have access to the user's session variables?
 - No, you should send whatever information you need along with the message payload. Database, and other third party, lookups should be limited. At some point payload size becomes a concern.

Comment: Thanks.  You mean accessing a MySQL DB in the GearMan invoked PHP script is not a good idea?  Do you know at what point the payload size gets to be a cause for concern?  100s of bytes, 1000s of bytes...

Comment: It's not always a bad idea to access mysql from a gearman worker. It's just a guideline I've followed with positive results: If you have the information when adding a job to Gearman, pass it along with the message instead of asking the worker to make an extra DB call. AFAIK jobs are stored in memory, so if you start running into memory issues then you need to start looking at your payload sizes.